# How to exclude code from CSS style sheet

Tags: html, css

So I have navigation bar that uses the HTML code

```
<ul>

<li><a href="imageline.html"> Home </a></li> 
<li><a href="fl.html">FL Studio</a></li>
<li><a href="flm.html">FL Studio Mobile</a></li>
<li><a href="plugin.html">Plugins/VST's</a></li>
<li><a href="signup.html"> Sign Up Now </a></li>

</ul>
```

The CSS to make the navigation bar is:

```
a   {color: black;
    text-decoration: none}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}
```

I would like to exclude a part of my webpage where I need to put social media links and other information in a list from this code. Because if I use the li or any list it comes up with black. Do you know how I would do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just use more specific selectors, for example

```
ul.my-custom-menu li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Instead of

```
a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Side note: If you use a CSS pre-processor like SASS, LESS etc it's easier to manage the context of your styles.